# detach std::thread running in background

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool

I was reading about the C++ threading. I encounter a example where an DocumentEditor was created. In the document editor whenever user opens a new document a new thread is created and that thread is immediately detached.

That detached thread would become a deamon thread when the document editing task will complete.

So my question is that if the user keeps the application opens for days and keep on creating new documents say 100s of them than the deamon thread count will keep on increasing ?

Or the deamons will be destroyed when the process is less on resources ?

Comment: Why the "threadpool" tag? I don't see anything in your question related to threadpools.

Comment: This is a question about an unnamed specific application. Nobody can answer your question without looking into that application.

Comment: What do you mean by daemon thread? And have you looked up what std::thread::detach does?

Comment: Once a detached `std::thread` ends execution, its resources will be released.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about the book [Practical Multithreading](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988770). The writer there was just giving an example of how threads can be useful and how detach can be used.

The writer didn't intend on covering every corner case. He just was giving an example on how detaching threads could be used. It's up to you how to deal with limited resources. It's like giving you an M6 screw and a screw-driver, and then you decide what to do with them. You can use the screw for a lamp, or a computer, or even maybe misuse it and put it in an M5 hole and break stuff. The context of using the screw and the screw-driver is a different one, and me giving an example about a lamp doesn't mean I'm explaining how a lamp works and it's electricity consumption, just like the context of having multiple threads is different than how you manage resources. It's up to you and up to your application's special case.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to this same example. But I still did not get the answer that when a thread is detached, what is the life time of that thread. Does the memory for detached thread is freed once the execution ended will it remain till the lifetime of process?